# When selecting an option from the dropdown selection box created via d3.js the value sent to the button becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, html-select

This code below is perfectly suited for testing, I just used it in `Visual Studio Code` (https://code.visualstudio.com/) and created the page from the `Live Server` extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer):

```
<html>
    <head>
        </style>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left">
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-1">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-1">
                        <button class="button" id="botao-do-radar-1" onclick="funcao_radar_1()">Radar 1</button>
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-1" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <iframe id="iframe-do-radar-1" width="100%" height="282" frameBorder="0" src="">
                </iframe>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
                    var select_1 = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1")
                    .append("select")
                    .attr("id","select-box-1")
                    .style("width","100%");
                    
                    function caixa_suspensa_1(data) {
                    select_1
                        .on("change", function(d) {
                        var value_1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                        document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-1').value = value_1;
                        var value_1_2 = d3.select(this).property("market");
                        document.querySelector('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').action = value_1_2;
                        });
                    let update_1 = select_1.selectAll("option")
                        .data(data);
                    update_1.exit().remove();
                    update_1.enter().append("option").merge(update_1)
                        .attr("value", d => d.value)
                        .attr("market", d => d.market)
                        .text(d => d.label);
                    }
                    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(data){caixa_suspensa_1(data)});
                </script>
                <form id="botao-de-jogo-betfair-1" action="" target="_blank">
                    <input type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="Jogo Betfair 1"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The path that generates the `action="undefined"` value is this:

```
var value_1_2 = d3.select(this).property("market");
document.querySelector('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').action = value_1_2;
```

---

`CSV` file `"Lista_de_Jogos.csv"` is:

```
label,value,market
,,
hotel,bus,party
house,car,work
```

---

The selection box perfectly shows both attributes:

```
<option value="car" market="work">house</option>
```

---

But when I select this `<option> house`, instead of `action` of `#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1` keep the value `work` he gets the value `undefined`:

```
<form id="botao-de-jogo-betfair-1" action="undefined" target="_blank">
                    <input type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="Jogo Betfair 1">
                </form>
```

---

Note: when I try to use `.property("value");` returns the value `car`perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `market` attribute from `select` tag instead of selected `option` tag which contains the `market` attribute. to solve this you just need to get the option which has been selected and then get the value using `attr`.

```js
var value_1_2 = d3.select(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("market");
document.querySelector('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').action = value_1_2;
```

---

Another improvement that you can make is instead of searching for the from we can give the form name and use that to access form from documemt

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-1">
    ...
</form>
```

then in javascript

```
var value_1_2 = d3.select(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("market");
document.forms["myform"].action = value_1_2;
```

Comment: Hi @Chandan It solved my problem perfectly, the bounty can only be given in 13 hours, as soon as possible I will confirm the delivery for you, realy thanks for all mate!

Comment: And @Chandan thanks so much for the other improvement tip, thank you so much for that, anything you see that you think deserves an improvement, feel free!

Comment: @BrondbyIF no issue, another improvement I would suggest is to move the `select_1.on` outside of caixa_suspensa_1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick with D3 here:

```
var value_1_2 = d3.select(this).property("market");
d3.select('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').attr('action', value_1_2);
```

I don't think there's any action property in Element.

Comment: Hello @SmokeyShakers , thanks for your attention, if I put ```d3.select``` instead of ```document.select```, nothing happens and the attribute is not created. So, in this case, your indication did not have positive effects, unfortunately.